# Pandoc vs LaTeXML for LaTeX conversion

Tags: pandoc, conversion, latexml

Why would we use LaTeXML for conversion instead of pandoc?

I see ar5ix uses LaTeXML instead of pandoc, which seems to be more widely known. I assume this is because LaTeXML renders latex better. However, pandoc seems very well maintained - would they not just copy over the AST converter from LaTeXML in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Note: I am the creator of ar5iv and a developer of LaTeXML, so my answer will come from that perspective.

Your question hits on a couple of important points.

- Yes, pandoc is well-maintained and has a very large community of contributors. That said, LaTeXML also has very stable full-time maintenance, courtesy of the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) and their DLMF project. We also have a more modest, but just as enthusiastic, team of external contributors.
- Separately, LaTeXML has been a partner to a long-term effort of the KWARC research group that has been gradually working away specifically on converting arXiv's articles, starting all the way back in 2006. In the process, we have created our own [conversion dashboard](https://corpora.mathweb.org/corpus/arxmliv/tex%5Fto%5Fhtml) and worked to provide support for the highest-impact packages. That got us to ar5iv, and brought us near the 80% mark for successful conversions to HTML.
- There is no LaTeX AST I am afraid. That is a big part of the difficulty (and inconsistency) in trying to find a map to HTML. Yes, one could argue a `\section` may imply an HTML `<section>`, but as soon as we start talking about constructs such as `\refstepcounter` and custom macros and environments, there is a lot less clarity. The choice of which pieces get preserved - and at which levels of abstraction - becomes an open-ended problem with various equally reasonable answers.

So, the long-and-short of how to make the choice between "latexml" and "pandoc" is to consider where the tools place their focus - and maybe compare their outputs on your concrete document.

If you are planning to submit your article to arXiv, there may be additional benefit in ensuring it converts well with LaTeXML, so that ar5iv (and eventually arXiv itself) will offer a high-quality HTML version.

If you are working on your own custom toolchain, and/or prefer to work with templates, and/or need an output format which isn't supported by LaTeXML, then pandoc could be a better fit.

Last but not least, these aren't your only options - there are over 10 different tools, in 8+ programming languages, trying to do LaTeX-to-HTML specifically. I have a brief overview of them as a slide in an ar5iv talk, in case that's of interest: [ar5iv talk, slide 19](https://prodg.org/talks/welcome_to_ar5iv#19)

Comment: Slightly unrelated to this question, but would you know if it is better to use pandoc to convert from latex to markdown or to use latexml to convert from latex to xml and pandoc to convert from xml to markdown? It [looks like](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19786519) latexml has the better latex parser, but cannot output markdown

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Pandoc's output formats are a superset of LaTeXML's. Does LaTeXML have better output for its supported formats than pandoc? Why was LaTeXML created instead of contributing to pandoc?

Comment: @olivarb - I think markdown is a relatively easy case almost equally supported by all converters, based on [Slide 20 in Deyan's answer](https://prodg.org/talks/welcome_to_ar5iv#20)

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but I think one of the links on your presentation is to a restricted twitter account (https://twitter.com/polymonyrks/status/1489990675903180800)

Comment: LaTeXML's XML is a custom project-specific schema, and I am not aware of other third-party projects interoperating with it. You should instead consider converting to a standard format that latexml supports, such as HTML, TEI, JATS. Then you might be able to use pandoc to map that into markdown.

Comment: LaTeXML was started in 2004, and is two years older than pandoc. Pandoc's aims are also different - they do not have a goal to have full coverage of TeX/LaTeX, while LaTeXML indeed has that as an idealized goal we aim for. Back in 2004 there were concrete reasons why the DLMF project decided to start a new conversion effort, instead of using the then existing mainstream converters - tex4ht, latex2html or tralics. Pandoc was not the first project on the scene.